# Setting up string security descriptor to give read access to elevated user

Tags: windows, winapi

I'm using `ConvertStringSecurityDescriptorToSecurityDescriptor` to create a security descriptor that I can then use with `CreateFile` as it is much easier and much more readable.

My intent is for the file to be fully controllable by its owner/creator and readable only by elevated processes.

I thus came up with the following SSDL string:

```
  SSDL :=
    'O:'+ SIDAsString  +                   // owner is user
    'D:' +                                 // Discretionary ACL
    'P' +                                  // protected
    '(A;NP;FA;;;' + SIDAsString + ')' +    // Full control to owner
    // Read only access to administrators 
    '(A;NP;FR;;;LA)' +
    '(A;NP;FR;;;BA)';
```

`SIDAsString` contains a valid `SID`, such as `S-1-5-18` for instance.

`ConvertStringSecurityDescriptorToSecurityDescriptor` returns a valid security descriptor and the file gets created with the rights that I expected.

However, elevated processes (such as an uninstaller for instance) cannot read the file, they get an access denied error.
If the process that tries to read the file is started via the `run as administrator` option, it receives access as expected.

I tried looking for the elevated user `SID`, but I could not find any mention of it, which leads me to believe that there is no such thing.

Short of giving read access to everyone, is there a way to specify a SSDL string that gives read access to a process running with elevated privileges?

Comment: Elevation does not change a user's SID or group associations, only its token permissions. The same user can run elevated and non-elevated processes. AFAIK, you can't use a Security Descriptor to grant/revoke access based on elevation status. I think you need to read up on what elevation actually is and how it works. Perhaps the reading app can try enabling the `SE_BACKUP_NAME` permission for itself and then open the file with the `FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS` flag enabled. That might grant the read access you are looking for.

Comment: @RemyLebeau - when process run not elevated under UAC - he have  `Administrators` (`S-1-5-32-544`) but with `SE_GROUP_USE_FOR_DENY_ONLY` attribute. when process started elevated - he have `Administrators` (`S-1-5-32-544`) with `SE_GROUP_ENABLED` - so really exist different with group associations. if we let access only for  `Administrators` (`S-1-5-32-544`) - elevated process will be have access but not elevated - no

Comment: "However, elevated processes cannot read the file" - vs "If the process started via the run as administrator option, it receives access as expected." - so can elevated process read file or not ? and `(A;NP;FR;;;LA)` or may be need `(A;NP;FRFX;;;LA)` for enable execute access on file too ?

Comment: @RbMm: `SE_GROUP_USE_FOR_DENY_ONLY` and `SE_GROUP_ENABLED` are not users/groups that a security descriptor can refer to. They are simply token attributes that control how SIDs are compared to a security descriptor's ACEs. So you still cannot tailor a security descriptor to grant/reject access based on the elevated status of a user/group using attributes.

Comment: @RemyLebeau - "you can't use a Security Descriptor to grant/revoke access based on elevation status." - this not true. simply example - `c:\windows` folder - elevated user can create/change files in this folder when not elevated can not. because `Administrators` have write permission for write, but not elevated user have this SID in token, but it used for Denny only

Comment: @RemyLebeau - i and say of course about token difference between elevated/not elevated users. and this let use DACL for restrict not elevated only. how `%windows%` or say `%program files%` let create files here for elevated and disable for not elevated ?

Comment: @RbMm: do you understand how UAC assigns access tokens to elevated vs non-elevated processes? Non-elevated processes are assigned a [restricted user token](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379316.aspx), whereas elevated processes are assigned an unrestricted user token. A restricted token has fewer privileges available than an unrestricted token. That is why non-elevated processes have restricted access to higher-secured items, even when running as an admin user. Even admins don't have full access unless they run an elevated process.

Comment: @RemyLebeau - you mistake. differents in tokens not only in privileges set (fewer rights) but in SID groups too. both have `S-1-5-32-544` (Administrators) in token but with different attributes - not elevated have this group with `SE_GROUP_USE_FOR_DENY_ONLY` - only because this he can not create files in `windows` folder. when provilege not used in file create process (when we not use `FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS`) - so you serious mistake

Comment: `I tried looking for the elevated user SID` - this is `S-1-5-32-544` - which have active only elevated users

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129373/discussion-between-remy-lebeau-and-rbmm).

Answer (score 0):

> I tried looking for the elevated user SID

this SID is `S-1-5-32-544` ( `Administrators` ). every process have token, token containing [`TOKEN_GROUPS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379624(v=vs.85).aspx) which containing [`SID_AND_ATTRIBUTES`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379595(v=vs.85).aspx) array. for same admin user when it started elevated or not elevated - this array is different. both (elevated and not elevated) admins have `S-1-5-32-544` but with different attributes ! elevated admin have it with `SE_GROUP_ENABLED` but not elevated (restricted) admin with [`SE_GROUP_USE_FOR_DENY_ONLY`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379596(v=vs.85).aspx)

> A SID with this attribute is a deny-only SID. When the system performs
>   an access check, it checks for access-denied ACEs that apply to the
>   SID, but it ignores access-allowed ACEs for the SID.

so this is key point - we need create SD with DACL where we enable appropriate access to `S-1-5-32-544` ( `Administrators` ) only (and say to `system` too)- as result elevated process will be have access to file, when not elevated - no.

demo: we create SD with next access in `DACL` rules:

```
001F01FF S-1-5-18 SYSTEM
001200A9 S-1-5-32-544 Administrators
```

so all access to `SYSTEM` and read/execute to `Administrators` - file with this `DACL` not elevated process (say notepad) can not even open for read-only. when elevated notepad - can open and read. but cannot write or delete

*note: for set `SYSTEM` as owner we need `SE_RESTORE_PRIVILEGE`*

```
void TestX()
{
    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa = { sizeof(sa) };

    if (ConvertStringSecurityDescriptorToSecurityDescriptor(
        L"O:SYD:P(A;NP;FA;;;SY)(A;NP;FRFX;;;BA)", 
        SDDL_REVISION_1, &sa.lpSecurityDescriptor, 0))
    {
        HANDLE hToken;
        if (OpenProcessToken(NtCurrentProcess(), TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES, &hToken))
        {
            static ::TOKEN_PRIVILEGES tp = {
                1, { { { SE_RESTORE_PRIVILEGE }, SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED|SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED_BY_DEFAULT } }
            };
            AdjustTokenPrivileges(hToken, FALSE, &tp, sizeof(tp), 0, 0);
            CloseHandle(hToken);
        }

        HANDLE hFile = CreateFile(L"c:\\windows\\1.txt", FILE_GENERIC_WRITE, 0, &sa, CREATE_NEW, 0, 0);

        if (hFile != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        {
            ULONG cb;
            WriteFile(hFile, "1234567890", 10, &cb, 0);
            CloseHandle(hFile);
        }

        LocalFree(sa.lpSecurityDescriptor);
    }
}
```

you can test how elevated/not elevated process (say notepad.exe) open this file.